# How to get the data-value of selected td

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to get a `data` value from the clicked `td`, which opens a modal with the informations of the user.
When I select all users, everything works fine..
But when I want to search a specific user (table is not displayed until you search for a user), the modal shows not the right data..

I created a JS array with the usernames and put it in my `data` value. The innerHTML from the column is the first- and last name of the user.

The problem is that when I click on the name the modal shows the information from the FIRST user in my array (grouped by lastname ASC)

I'm using the DataTables plugin. Here's a short example of my `drawCallback` function:

```js
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
  var api = this.api();
  var rows = api.rows({
    page: 'current'
  }).nodes();
  var last = null;

  api.column(0, {
    page: 'current'
  }).data().each(function(group, i) {
    if (last !== group) {
      var groupName = api.row(i).data();
      $(rows).eq(i).before(
         '<tr class="group"><td style="font-weight: bold;" data-value="'+groupName[0]+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileModal" class="tdPerson" colspan="1">'+group+'</td><td colspan="5"></td></tr>'
      );

      last = group;
    }
  });
}
```

Here's my AJAX request:

```
$('.table').on('click', '.tdPerson', function(event) {
  id = $(this).attr('data-value');
  $.ajax({
    url: "getData.php",
    data: {
      type: "getPersonModal",
      data: id
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#profileModalContent').html(data);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an element with the class `tdPerson` in the HTML you're creating.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, my fault.. updated the post above..

Comment: Thanks. In that case what you have should work. Try `console.log(id)` and see what the console shows. Also note that using `data()` is a better idea that `attr()`, ie. `$(this).data('value')`, but that won't be affecting the outcome

Comment: It works, wenn I select all users in the table. But when I just want to search one specific user, the data-value is always the first username in my array..

Comment: Always look at the *rendered* HTML (right click, view source) to see what it's doing (or inspect element).  In this case, this looks suspicious: `data-value="'+groupName[0]+'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a confirmation Modal with columns data on button click using Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673651/how-to-display-a-confirmation-modal-with-columns-data-on-button-click-using-data)

Comment: @freedomn-m My console shows the username which is always the first user in my array.

Comment: @ygorbunkov nope.. thats another issue he had. also he just wanted an alert to be displayed. I want a modal with all information of the user

Comment: @MertSilva isn't that the problem as described?

Comment: @freedomn-m no.. I wish it is.. looked everywhere in the internet but I could'nt find a solution

Comment: @Mert Silva: Question header states clearly '**confirmation Modal**'. The answer shows solution with alert (rather than modal) for simplicity sake. Capturing the data model of the clicked row is essential part, make up modal instead of alert is not a big deal, whatsoever.

Comment: I have answered similar question yet another time (this time calling bootstrap **modal**), you might find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930978/datatables-show-column-data-in-modal/