# DataTables-show column data in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a column in my table that is a long string. So i'm trying to show it in a popup modal.

When i click the button to launch the modal, the page just refreshes and nothing is even printed to console.

HTML of Modal:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 id="modalTitle"></h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is snippet in DataTable creation.

```
{ data: 'Journal',
        render: function(data, type, row) {return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-Journal="'+data+'" data-target="#myModal">'+"Details"+'</button>'} },
```

The modal show event. Nothing is printed in console so i'm guessing the error is before here.

```
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var triggerLink = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var journal = triggerLink.data("Journal");
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
    console.log(journal);
    $("modalTitle").text("Title");
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html("<h5>"+journal+"</h5>");});
```

Comment: Is it possible the instantiation of your modal is before your listener? The order is important, and can prevent that `show.bs.modal` event from firing properly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279629/bootstrap-jquery-show-bs-modal-event-wont-fire

Comment: Are you trying to display inside your modal data entries from particular column for entire table (all rows) or for certain row only?

Comment: Regardless of the two, I can't spot where in your code you're trying to access DataTable data.

Comment: Please, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your button to **type = button** as its default is **submit**'

```
    render: function(data, type, row) {return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-Journal="'+data+'" type="button" data-target="#myModal">'+"Details"+'</button>'} },
```

Comment: Yeah that worked to show modal. The journal data is still not populating. And console logs not showing either.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide any relevant details regarding your use case, I've made up my own example, which delivers major idea, though:

```js
//make up random source for DataTable
const tableSrc = [...Array(5)].map((item, index) => {
  const rowObj = {};
  rowObj.user = 'user'+(index+1);
  rowObj.ip = [...Array(4)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random()*140)+10).join('.');
  rowObj.hash = [...Array(256)].map(() => String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*(126-33))+33)).join('');
  return rowObj;
});
//initialize DataTable
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: tableSrc,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Username', data: 'user'},
    {title: 'IP address', data: 'ip'},
    {
      title: 'Hash',
      data: 'hash',
      render: data => `<span>******</span><button class="showhash">show</button>`
    }
  ]
});
//display 'hash' property for particular row upon clicking the button
$('#mytable').on('click', 'button', function(){
  const clickedRow = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr'));
  const modalTitle = `Hash for ${clickedRow.data().user}`;
  const modalBody = clickedRow.data().hash;
  $('#mymodal .modal-title').text(modalTitle);
  $('#mymodal .modal-body').text(modalBody);
  $('#mymodal').modal('toggle');
});
```

```css
td button {
  float:right
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--jQuery DataTables prerequisites-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <!--bootstrap prerequisites-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!--DataTable-->
  <table id="mytable"></table>
  <!--Bootstrap modal-->
  <div id="mymodal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```